# Need help to improve the below query (Cte based solution)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

Consider the below input table

```
Id  CountryName
1   India,Australia,Singapore,Pakistan,Bangaladesh
2   Norway,Argentina,Brazil,WestIndies,Burma
```

Desired output being

```
Id  Country1    Country2    Country3    Country4    Country5
1   India   Australia   Singapore   Pakistan    Bangalades
2   Norway  Argentina   Brazil  WestIndies  Burma
```

I have writen the query as under which works fine

```
;WITH cte AS (

SELECT 
Id,
CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(CountryName, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML) AS names
FROM @t
)

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
Id,
x.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS Country,
'Country' + CAST(s.Number AS VARCHAR) AS CountryType
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values s 
CROSS APPLY names.nodes('//i[position()=sql:column("s.number")]') x(i)
WHERE s.type='p'
) a
PIVOT (
MAX(Country) FOR CountryType IN (Country1, Country2, Country3, Country4,Country5)
) pvt
```

But performancewise it is very bad... 
I am looking for a better query that can speed up the process (that may not be xquery approach of mine but other approach using cTE only and no RBar/procedural/while loop/cursor approach)

Even I am fine with if my query can be improved.

N.B.~ I cannot add any indexing on the table..please consider this point as a limitation to the enviromnent. Whatever I have to do is with the query only.

N.B.~ There can be more countries and not confined to 5

Please help....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [parsename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) if you have a four part string separated by `.`. Since you have five countries you can get the first with a regular substring and then remove the first country, replace all `,` with `.` and use `parsename` for the rest

```
declare @T table(Id int,  CountryName varchar(50))
insert into @T values
(1,   'India,Australia,Singapore,Pakistan,Bangaladesh'),
(2,   'Norway,Argentina,Brazil,WestIndies,Burma')

select Id,
  substring(CountryName, 1, charindex(',', CountryName)-1) as Country1,
  parsename(T.N, 4) as Country2,
  parsename(T.N, 3) as Country3,
  parsename(T.N, 2) as Country4,
  parsename(T.N, 1) as Country5
from @T
  cross apply(select replace(stuff(CountryName, 1, charindex(',', CountryName), ''), ',', '.')) as T(N)
```

If you know that you have 8 countries you can do this.

```
declare @T table(Id int,  CountryName varchar(100))
insert into @T values
(1,   'India,Australia,Singapore,Pakistan,Bangaladesh,Denmark,Germany,France'),
(2,   'Norway,Argentina,Brazil,WestIndies,Burma,South Africa,Spain,Portugal')


select Id,
  parsename(T1.N, 4) as Country1,
  parsename(T1.N, 3) as Country2,
  parsename(T1.N, 2) as Country3,
  parsename(T1.N, 1) as Country4,
  parsename(T2.N, 4) as Country5,
  parsename(T2.N, 3) as Country6,
  parsename(T2.N, 2) as Country7,
  parsename(T2.N, 1) as Country8
from @T
  cross apply(select charindex(',', CountryName, charindex(',', CountryName, charindex(',', CountryName, charindex(',', CountryName)+1)+1)+1)) as S(P)
  cross apply(select replace(substring(CountryName, 1, S.P-1), ',', '.')) as T1(N)
  cross apply(select replace(stuff(CountryName, 1, S.P, ''), ',', '.')) as T2(N)
```

If you don't know how many countries you have you need to build the query dynamically. [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)